# How to shift edge labels along edges in tkz-graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tkz-graph

Using tkz-graph package I often feel the need to move a little bit the labels on the edges, that are always positioned midway the edge. In this example I would move the label `0.5` from node `a` to node `d` closer to node `d` to avoid intersection with a red box. Here a MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \GraphInit[vstyle=Normal]
        \SetGraphUnit{1.5}
        \Vertices{circle}{a,b,c,d,e}
        \Edge[label=1](a)(b)
        \Edge[label=2](a)(c)
        \Edge[label=0.5](a)(d)
        \Edge[label=3](a)(e)
        \node[draw=red!50,rounded corners=5mm,fit=(b.north) (a.south) (c.west) (a.east)](BORD) {};
    \node[right of=BORD,anchor=west,inner sep=1cm]{$\mathcal{G}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:
[image: tikzgraph example]

How to mode the `0.5` label along the edge and not always in the center?

Comment: `\Edge[label=0.5,style={pos=.4}](a)(d)`?

Comment: So simple! You saved my day!

Comment: @linello What font did you use for this example?

Comment: It's the font used in the arsclassica package, an addition to the classicthesis font. I think it's a Palatino based font family.

Comment: The  the font of the $G$ it's Euler, still in the arsclassica package.

Answer (score 7):

The `\Edge` macro is only syntactic sugar for basic TikZ which draw a path and places a node on it.  Nodes on paths can receive the `pos` key to indicate at what fraction the node is to be placed.  To set node option in `\Edge` you have to wrap them in the `style` option, i.e.

```
\Edge[label=0.5,style={pos=.3}](a)(d)
```

to place the node at one third of the path starting from `(a)`.  For your example I chose `pos=.25`.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \GraphInit[vstyle=Normal]
  \SetGraphUnit{1.5}
  \Vertices{circle}{a,b,c,d,e}
  \Edge[label=1](a)(b)
  \Edge[label=2](a)(c)
  \Edge[label=0.5,style={pos=.25}](a)(d)
  \Edge[label=3](a)(e)
  \node[draw=red!50,rounded corners=5mm,fit=(b.north) (a.south) (c.west) (a.east)](BORD) {};
  \node[right of=BORD,anchor=west,inner sep=1cm]{$\mathcal{G}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]